PyTorch model training with DataLoader is too slow
I'm training a very small NN using the HAM10000 dataset. For loading the data I'm using the DataLoader that ships with PyTorch:
class CocoDetectionWithFilenames(CocoDetection):
    def __init__(self, root: str, ann_file: str, transform=None):
        super().__init__(root, ann_file, transform)

    def get_filename(self, idx: int) -> str:
        return self.coco.loadImgs(self.ids[idx])[0]["file_name"]


def get_loaders(root: str, ann_file: str) -> tuple[CocoDetection, DataLoader, DataLoader, DataLoader]:
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
    dataset = CocoDetectionWithFilenames(
        root=root,
        ann_file=ann_file,
        transform=transform
    )
    train_size = int(0.7 * len(dataset))
    valid_size = int(0.15 * len(dataset))
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size - valid_size
    train_dataset, valid_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, valid_size, test_size])
    num_workers = os.cpu_count()
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        pin_memory=True,
        prefetch_factor=1024
    )
    valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        pin_memory=True,
        prefetch_factor=1024
    )
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=num_workers,
        pin_memory=True
    )

    return dataset, train_loader, valid_loader, test_loader

The thing is, when my training loop runs, the training itself is very fast, but the program spends 95% on the time inbetween epochs - probably loading the data:
def extract_bboxes(targets: list[dict]) -> list[torch.Tensor]:
    bboxes = []

    for target in targets:
        xs, ys, widths, heights = target["bbox"]

        for idx, _ in enumerate(xs):
            x1, y1, width, height = xs[idx], ys[idx], widths[idx], heights[idx]
            # Convert COCO format (x, y, width, height) to (x1, y1, x2, y2)
            x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height

            bboxes.append(torch.IntTensor([x1, y1, x2, y2]))

    return bboxes

num_epochs = 25
train_losses = []
val_losses = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0

    for images, targets in train_loader_tqdm:
        images = images.to(device)
        bboxes = extract_bboxes(targets)
        bboxes = torch.stack(bboxes).to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)

        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, bboxes)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

    epoch_train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)

    train_losses.append(epoch_train_loss)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {epoch_train_loss}")
    model.eval()

As you can see, the training loop code is quite simple, nothing weird happening there.

You can try to extract bounding boxes before training and then use that data, instead of doing it in training loop.

@maciek97x that's not the reason for the slowness. That function only loops over already loaded targets and reads the data. It's not doing any heavy lifting - basically that function takes almost no time. I updated my question so that you see it.

You can try to reduce num_workers and prefetch_factor. Maybe it spends all the time fetching that 1024 batches using all threads.

It seems you were right. Previously it was taking like 40 seconds to fetch the data and 8s to do the training, now it's fetching the data in 10s after reducing the num_workers value. Please post that as your answer, so that I can accept it.

Try to reduce num_workers and prefetch_factor. It may spend all the time fetching that 1024 batches using all threads.
